# In ASP.NET the ajax GET response is null when the HttpStateCode is 200

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I tried to get Logged User information with ajax GET request in ASP.NET project.
In browser the response code is 200, but I got "null" response.
Here is some codes I tried.

```
    function display(json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
    var config = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": ApiBaseUrl + "GetUserDetail",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": headers,
        "contenttype": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: display,
    };

    $.ajax(config).done(function (response) {
        if (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }

        console.log("No Data");
    });
```

Backend Controller code is:

```
        [Route("GetUserDetail")]
        [HttpGet()]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
                string email = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)
                               .Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
                IBOAccount _accountBO = IOContainer.Get<IBOAccount>();
                var _registeredUser = "response";
                return Ok(_registeredUser);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

What's wrong? It seems that there is no token information saved in cookie.

Comment: did you try only two line of code var _registeredUser = "response";
                return Ok(_registeredUser); may be exception in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no Token authorization, it can't work and the response is NULL.
By using "Authorization" in request headers, I got email address and name of logged user.

Here are some codes to use Token.

```
    var AuthData = JSON.parse(UserCustomService.getSessionStorage("Token")); //get Token
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + AuthData.access_token, // Bearer:type of Token
    };

    var GetUserInformation = function () {

        var config = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": ApiBaseUrl + "/GetUserInformation", // user defined route
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": headers
        };

        $.ajax(config).done(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log(response);
            } else console.log("NULL response");
        });
    }
```

Token should be in all request headers for getting and updating current user information in database because of security I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 5.2 (anything other than ASP.NET Core 1.X, 2.X), then you'll need to explicitly allow your get requests to return JSON via the [JsonRequestBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonrequestbehavior?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) property. So your return statement could look something like:

```
return Json(_registeredUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If you are using ASP.NET Core, then I'd maybe guess there is some exception occurring in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var AuthData = JSON.parse(UserCustomService.getSessionStorage("Token")); 
var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + AuthData.access_token, 
};
```